# Log4j2 JSON Layout: add custom date field in UTC

Tags: java, log4j2

The Log4j2 support [JSON Layout](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#JSONLayout), where I added an extra custom field in log4j2.xml:

```
<JsonLayout compact="true" eventEol="true" stacktraceAsString="true">
    <KeyValuePair key="@timestamp" value="$${date:yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'}"/>
</JsonLayout>
```

In general, all works fine, but this log handled by Filebeats and it assumes that date presented in UTC.

All log entries have date values in local time zone.

Is it possible somehow to output date in UTC?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can [create your own lookup](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/extending.html#Lookups) since, as I'm sure you already know, the `KeyValuePair` supports lookups in its value attribute per the [manual page you shared](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#JSONLayout).

For example purposes I created a simple lookup that uses [System.currentTimeMillis()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis--).

Here is the example code:

First, the lookup class:

```
package utcTime;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LogEvent;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.Plugin;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.lookup.StrLookup;

@Plugin(name = "UtcMillis", category = "Lookup")
public class UtcMillisLookup implements StrLookup{
    /**
     * Lookup the value for the key.
     * @param key  the key to be looked up, may be null
     * @return The value for the key.
     */
    public String lookup(String key) {
        return String.valueOf(getUTCMillis());
    }

    /**
     * @return current UTC time in milliseconds
     */
    private long getUTCMillis(){
        return System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    /**
     * Lookup the value for the key using the data in the LogEvent.
     * @param event The current LogEvent.
     * @param key  the key to be looked up, may be null
     * @return The value associated with the key.
     */
    public String lookup(LogEvent event, String key) {
        return String.valueOf(getUTCMillis());
    }
}
```

Next, the log4j2.xml configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <JsonLayout compact="true" eventEol="true" stacktraceAsString="true">
                <KeyValuePair key="@timestamp" value="$${UtcMillis:}"/>
            </JsonLayout>
        </Console>

    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Note that the lookup has no parameters/keys so you can leave that part empty/blank but you still have to use the colon (`:`) and this is why you see `$${UtcMillis:}` in the above configuration.

Finally, a simple class to generate a log event:

```
package utcTime;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class MainUtcLookup {
    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger();
    public static void main(String[] args){
        log.info("Here's some info!");
    }
}
```

Here is sample output:

```
{  
   "thread":"main",
   "level":"INFO",
   "loggerName":"utcTime.MainUtcLookup",
   "message":"Here's some info!",
   "endOfBatch":false,
   "loggerFqcn":"org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger",
   "instant":{  
      "epochSecond":1534642997,
      "nanoOfSecond":556000000
   },
   "threadId":1,
   "threadPriority":5,
   "@timestamp":"1534642997558"
}
```

I'm not going to delve into the details of all the different ways you can get the current time in UTC milliseconds as I'm sure you can research the details of that on your own. I just wanted to provide an example of how you could accomplish your primary goal of adding the millisecond timestamp to your log4j2 `JSONLayout`.

Hope this helps!